# Selenium Webdriver Autocomplete drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I am working with a registration page, I am having the basic fields like Salutation, First name, Last name and Address details.

The Salutation drop down structure is as follows,

```
<div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: 200px;">
<ul id="Salutation_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
<li id="0741907a-4369-4ac2-8100-3829655a7522" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Salutation</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="">Mr</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Mrs</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="3" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Miss</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="4" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Ms</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="5" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Dr</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="6" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Prof</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="7" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Rev</li>
</ul>
```

For selecting the Mr from the drop down values i have used the code as below,

```
String capColorDropDown = "//span[@role='listbox']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(capColorDropDown)).click();

String itemName = "Orange";
String listId = "color_listbox";
Thread.sleep(2000);

String xpathForItem = "//ul[@id='Salutation_listbox']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='Mr']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForItem)).click();
```

This code worked fine for me and i am able to select the Mr value for salutation, but now i have to complete the address details field in which the city field is a auto complete drop down and its structure is as follows,

```
<div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;">
<ul id="AddressDetails_City_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="">ALPURRURULAM, NT, Australia, 4825</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">ALPURRURULAM, null, Invalid, </li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">ALPURRURULAM, null, Invalid, </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to use the same code to access the ALPURRURULAM, NT, Australia, 4825 value as,

```
String capColorDropDown1 = "//span[@role='listbox']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(capColorDropDown1)).click();

String itemName1 = "Orange";
String listId1 = "color_listbox";
Thread.sleep(2000);

String xpathForItem1 = "//ul[@AddressDetails_City_listbox']/li[@class='k-item' and text()='ALPURRURULAM, NT, Australia, 4825']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForItem)).click();
```

But the selenium is accessing the `//span[@role='listbox]` and clicking again on the salutation drop down list. The city field also has same role as `listbox` but how can I differentiate and select the city field values?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using more specific locator as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("AddressDetails_City_listbox"));
el.click();

//now select desired option
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(el, By.cssSelector("li[data-offset-index='0']"))).click();
```

Comment: While executing the above comment, i am getting the error message as ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: @user3836485 in which line this exception occurred?? did right dropdown opened before exception or not??

Comment: First execute this line `driver.findElement(By.id("AddressDetails_City_listbox")).click();` and let me know this line is opening right dropdown or throwing an error??

Comment: No it is not opening the particular drop down, it throws ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: @user3836485 Ok, then could you share this dropdown HTML with `span` tag as well?? because in your provided HTML I didn't see any `span` element present.

Comment: There is no span for the drop down values, it is a auto generated drop down. It only has li

Comment: Then why are you using `"//span[@role='listbox']";` this xpath which would trying to locate span element as well??